# Acessing Values only at certain indexes using iterators

Tags: c++, algorithm, lambda, stl, iterator

I have a trouble understanding `std::accumulate`. Can it be used to add up the values at only even indices from a vector?

```
int rob(vector<int>& nums) {

    int a = std::accumulate(nums.begin(), nums.end(), 0);

   std::cout <<" a: " <<a; 
   return a;

}
```

So if I have a `vector y = {1, 2, 3, 4}`

How could I change the above code, so that `std::accumulate` only iterates over indices [0] and [2]. Is that even possible using `std::accumulate`?

Comment: `std::remove_if` seems likely to be what is needed.  That is, use of `std::accumulate` is correct.  The modification is to the range of iteration.  See http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/remove_if/, which has some examples.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a couple of choices. The quick and (really) dirty way is to walk across the whole collection, and invoke a function that keeps track of the current index, and ignores the values at the odd indices. It works, but it's ugly at best, and more importantly it's wrong on a rather fundamental level, forcing what's supposed to be an accumulation function to take responsibility for doing iteration. In short, this is much more of a problem than a solution.

The clean way would be to realize that visiting every other item in the collection is really about *iteration*, not about a specific algorithm (`std::accumulate` or any other). So what we should be using here is an iterator that visits the items we want to visit. Here's a minimal implementation:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
#include <iostream>
#include <numeric>

template <class Iterator>
class n_iterator { 
     Iterator i;
     size_t n;
public:
    // We construct this iterator from some other iterator, plus a "step" value
    // to tell us how many items to skip forward when `++` is applied.
    n_iterator(Iterator i, size_t n) : i(i), n(n) {}

    // When you dereference this iterator, it's equivalent to dereferencing
    // the underlying iterator.
    typename std::iterator_traits<Iterator>::value_type operator *() { return *i; }

    // ...but when you increment it, you move ahead N places instead of 1.
    n_iterator &operator++() { std::advance(i, n); return *this; }

    // iterator comparisons just compare the underlying iterators.
    bool operator==(n_iterator const &other) const { return i == other.i; }
    bool operator!=(n_iterator const &other) const { return i != other.i; }
};

int main() { 
    std::vector<int> y { 1, 2, 3, 4};
    auto total = std::accumulate(y.begin(), y.end(), 0);

    std::cout << "total: " << total << "\n";

    auto skip_total = std::accumulate(n_iterator(y.begin(), 2), n_iterator(y.end(), 2), 0);

    std::cout << "Skipped total: " << skip_total << "\n";
}
```

This implementation seems to suffice for g++ 7.1 to compile the code, but for real use, you should probably implement the entire interface for an iterator (e.g., as a minimum, it should really have definitions for `value_type`, `reference`, etc.)

For the moment, this also supplies only a forward iterator, regardless of the underlying iterator. Depending on the situation (and category of underlying iterator) you could also support bidirectional and/or random iteration.

Comment: This is very similar to [`boost::strided_iterator`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_71_0/libs/compute/doc/html/boost/compute/strided_iterator.html)

Comment: @MarshallClow: ah, so it is--I guess I should have guessed that Boost would already have this.

Answer (score 3):

Here you are

```
int rob( const vector<int>& nums) {

    int i = 0;
    int a = std::accumulate(nums.begin(), nums.end(), 0,
                            [&i]( const auto &acc, const auto &value )
                            {
                                return ( i ^= 1 ) ? acc + value : acc;
                            } );

   std::cout <<" a: " <<a; 
   return a;

}
```

Here is a demonstrative program

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
#include <numeric>

int rob( const std::vector<int> &nums )
{
    int i = 0;

    int a = std::accumulate( std::begin( nums ), std::end( nums ), 0,
                             [&i]( const auto &acc, const auto &value )
                             {
                                return ( i ^= 1 ) ? acc + value : acc;
                             } );

   return a;
}

int main() 
{
    std::vector<int> v = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };

    std::cout << rob( v ) << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

Its output is

```
20
```

You can add one more parameter to the function that you could select whether to sum even or odd numbers. For example

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
#include <numeric>

int rob( const std::vector<int> &nums, bool odds = false )
{
    int i = odds;

    int a = std::accumulate( std::begin( nums ), std::end( nums ), 0,
                             [&i]( const auto &acc, const auto &value )
                             {
                                return ( i ^= 1 ) ? acc + value : acc;
                             } );

   return a;
}

int main() 
{
    std::vector<int> v = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };

    std::cout << rob( v ) << '\n';

    std::cout << rob( v, true ) << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
20
25
```

In this case you can remove the declaration of the variable i. For example

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
#include <numeric>

int rob( const std::vector<int> &nums, bool odds = false )
{
    int a = std::accumulate( std::begin( nums ), std::end( nums ), 0,
                             [&odds]( const auto &acc, const auto &value )
                             {
                                return ( odds = !odds ) ? acc + value : acc;
                             } );

   return a;
}

int main() 
{
    std::vector<int> v = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };

    std::cout << rob( v ) << '\n';

    std::cout << rob( v, true ) << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: could you please explain how the Lamda works? I do not get how it skips the value at odd indices.

Comment: @learningtocodecplusplus The expression i ^= 1 controls the indices. If i is equal to 0 then the expression is set to 1 and this part of the conditional statement acc + value is returned . If i is equal to 1 then the expression i ^= 1 is equal to 0 and the original value of acc is returned.

Comment: It is being unnecessarily clever. It changes the value of `I` between `0` and `1`, so it adds up every other element. if `i` was a boolean, alternating between `true` and `false`, it would be clearer.

Comment: Is it guaranteed that the _BinaryOperation_ will only be executed once per element, and in order? I don't think it is, and your solution relies on that.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I just this moment have looked through the Standard.:)